# Get numbers and characters after a matching string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm trying to get the value after matched strings:

```
Empregados/Avulsos 2.912,30
Empregados/Avulsos 7.310,06
```

Sometimes there is a string in the value.

Is this possible with regular expressions?

I was trying like this:

```
    var match = data.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');

    var match_two = match.match([\n\r][ \t]*Retenção Lei 9.711/98[ \t]*([^\n\r]*));
    console.log(match_two);
```

First I replace all spaces with one. Then I try to get the value `'Retenção Lei 9.711/98'`. But the output is `'2'`.

I want to make a regular expression which will always get the next word or number in these examples:

```
Hour: get 12:12
Data: get 24/08
Solicitação get 2.912,30
Empregados/Avulsos get 1.452,00
Palavras separadas get 2.912,30
```

Words:

```
'Solicitação',
'Retention xxx 9.999/99'
'Compensation'
'TET':
'VALUE - SOCIAL PREVÎ',
'VALUE - OTHERS',
'TOTAL TO GET',
'TABLES',
'COD GPX:',
'FXGE:',
'ALIX DC:',
'RXG AJUST',
'DATA:',
'HOUR:',
```

Comment: What are you trying to get again?

Comment: the numbers in the right ->. Sorry, my english is poor.

Comment: `/\s\s+/` can be replaced with `/\s{2,}/`

Comment: I'm trying to get the next word or number in the right of some word.

Comment: Can you provide expected match for each sample input you have in question?

Comment: Yes! give me a second!

Comment: i edited the question @anubhava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll address the following problem. You have a piece of text containing words and various numbers. Given an arbitrary substring, you want to find the first occurrence of that substring and extract the first number that follows it.

For example, if the substring were `'Total'`, you would want to use this regular expression:

```
/Total.*?(\d\S*)/
```

Let me break it down:

- `Total` is the substring you're looking for
- `.*` means that you're looking for any character zero or more times
- `?` means that you want to match as few characters as possible
- `(` opens the capturing group: these are the characters you want to extract
- `\d` matches a digit
- `\S*` matches anything except a whitespace character, zero or more times
- `)` closes the capturing group

Note that `.` matches any character except line-ending characters like `\n` and `\r`. If your text includes such characters, you'll want to replace them with the visible space character (`' '`) before applying the above regular expression. If your text is assigned to the variable `text`, you can do the following to replace all whitespace characters (including line-ending characters) with visible spaces:

```
text = text.replace(/\s/g, ' ');
```

One more important point is that `/Total.*?(\d\S*)/` is a fixed regular expression. If you want to make a regular expression for any given substring, you'll have to compile it with the `RegExp` constructor:

```
var re = new RegExp(substring + '.*?(\\d\\S*)');
```

Note that we're passing a string to the constructor, so we have to escape the slashes in specifying the regular expression. Where we wrote `\d\S` in the literal regular expression, we have to write `\\d\\S` in the string.

We can execute the compiled regular expression on a string with the [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method, test the result to see if it's `null`, and finally get the contents of the capturing group:

```
var match = re.exec(text);
if (match === null) {
  return '';
}
return match[1];
```

The snippet below implements this process in a function called `getNumberAfterSubstring(substring, text)`. Click on the blue button below the code to see it run on a piece of sample text and some sample substrings.

```js
function print(s) {
  document.write(s + '<br />');
}

function getNumberAfterSubstring(substring, text) {
  var re = new RegExp(substring + '.*?(\\d\\S*)'),
      match = re.exec(text);
  if (match === null) {
    return '';       // If no match is found, return empty string.
  }
  return match[1];   // Otherwise return first parenthesized group.
}

var text = "Tabela 25 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ultricies ultricies auctor. Donec sodales pharetra ante, vitae suscipit metus mollis quis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Retention Law 0.000/00 consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nisl dui, Compension 00,00 ullamcorper eget posuere et, faucibus ut leo. Ut tellus nisi, lobortis eget nibh id, laoreet tincidunt lacus. Integer eget libero Value - Social prevî: 715,86 ut nulla vestibulum viverra eget sit Value - Others: 715,86 amet nisi. Suspendisse potenti.\nCurabitur ligula felis, Data: 02/02/2011 scelerisque in consequat et, tempor non ipsum. Donec euismod, turpis ut accumsan lobortis, lectus felis ullamcorper nibh, et pretium lectus nisl at enim. Total to pay 863,37 Nullam faucibus massa vitae nulla ultrices, eu sollicitudin justo imperdiet. Phasellus at est scelerisque, egestas diam et, rutrum dui. Hour: 15:44:58 Nunc sagittis hendrerit dui, sit amet congue arcu efficitur eu. Praesent hendrerit ut nibh vel vehicula. Morbi mollis enim ex, at mollis libero pellentesque quis. Etiam sed bibendum nisi. COD GPS: 2100 In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi ac condimentum eros, in egestas tellus.";

text = text.replace(/\s/g, ' ');  // Replace line-ending characters.
text = text.toLocaleLowerCase();

var substrings = ['Retention Law', 'Compension', 'VALUE - SOCIAL PREVî',
                  'Total', 'Tabela', 'Hour', 'Data'];

for (var i = 0; i < substrings.length; ++i) {
  var substring = substrings[i].toLocaleLowerCase();
  print(substring + ': ' + getNumberAfterSubstring(substring, text));
}
```

Comment: Michael. Should i scape or something if i want pass some word with accented characters?

Comment: i'm receiving an empty string when i try to use with VALUE - SOCIAL PREVî

Comment: Maybe because it's capitalized. You can write `new RegExp(substring + '.*?(\\d\\S*)', 'i')` to match regardless of case. The difference is the new parameter `'i'`. Does it work now?

Comment: doesn't @michael laszlo :/

Comment: you are right, capitalize values is being ignored. Can be fixed?

Comment: Can you try pull in your code when some letter is with accentuation?

Comment: I ran the code with "VALUE - SOCIAL PREVî" and it worked. I'm not sure what other examples you have. Maybe the lowercase rules are different in Portuguese. Just now I added `toLocaleLowerCase()` to the text and the substrings. That renders everything to lowercase in a location-sensitive manner.

Comment: Could i ask the last question? I see the Regex ignore value letters because we are asking for digits only. What should i change to accept letters two? I was trying to add \L

Comment: To match a letter, write `\w` in the regular expression. To match two letters, `\w\w` or `\w{2}`. To match one or more letters in a row, `\w\w*`.

Comment: Michael, this is crazy, i already made some courses about regex and i can't learn this... it's madness

Comment: I see that you clicked the checkmark, but that's for accepting an answer. To award a bounty, you have to click the bounty award icon next to the answer.

Comment: Yep, i was in my iphone and i didn't find this icon haha. Sorry for the delay, i was thinking that accept would be enough. Hei Michael, in this past days i was trying to study more regex, do you have any blog post, tutorial or something related that you can share with me? :)

Comment: I think the best way to master regular expressions is to keep using them to solve various tasks. You'll figure out what you need as you go along. You will learn faster if you test your regular expressions frequently and study the results to see why you get what you did. There are various regex testing sites that can help you with this by highlighting the components of your regular expression and explaining what each one does. For example, take a look at this example that I just posted on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/wI0iW8/1

Comment: Thanks Michae! Do you want won more 200 points? I have other question about regex :B

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx capture groups don't include decimals or commas, but the numeric values have those.

```
var res = /Empregados\/Avulsos ([\d\.,:\/]+)/.exec(str);
if(res[1]){
   var values = res[1].split(",");
}
```

In Regex, the *\d* find digits, not numbers. The numbers in your example can be made of several digits, decimal points, commas, colons, and slashes.

Just make sure to include that stuff in your regex.

Comment: can't use split in res @jairbow.

Comment: My bad. Fixed. I just had get the captured value inside "res". @AmandaFerrari